# Proving identity $\binom{2n}{n}2^{-2n} = (-1)^n \binom{-\frac{1}{2}}{n}$

Tags: combinatorics

The identity is taken from [Feller "An Introduction to Probability Theory and Its Applications", Volume 1, chapter II, p.12 ex.5](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/An+Introduction+to+Probability+Theory+and+Its+Applications%2C+Volume+1%2C+3rd+Edition-p-9780471257080) and it is later used in chapter XII.

$\binom{2n}{n}2^{-2n} = \frac{\overbrace{2n(2n-1)(2n-2)\ldots(2n-n+1)}^{n \text{factors}}}{n!}2^{-2n} = \frac{\overbrace{\frac{n}{2}(\frac{n}{2}-\frac{1}{4})(\frac{n}{2}-\frac{1}{2})\ldots(\frac{n}{2}-\frac{n-1}{4})}^{n \text{factors}}}{n!} \tag{1} \label{f}$

$(-1)^n \binom{-\frac{1}{2}}{n} = \frac{\overbrace{-\frac{1}{2}(-\frac{1}{2}-1)(-\frac{1}{2}-2)\ldots(-\frac{1}{2}-n+1)}^{n \text{factors}}}{n!}(-1)^{-n} = \frac{\overbrace{\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{2}+1)(\frac{1}{2}+2)\ldots(\frac{1}{2}+n-1)}^{n \text{factors}}}{n!} \tag{2} \label{s}$

The smallest factor in $\eqref{f}$'s nominator is $\frac{n}{2}-\frac{n-1}{4}$ which is greater than the smallest factor in $\eqref{s}$: $\frac{1}{2}$

It appears that
$\binom{2n}{n}2^{-2n} \neq (-1)^n \binom{-\frac{1}{2}}{n}$. Where am I wrong?

Comment: The second equality sign in (1) is false. The product on the very right has an $n+1$ that should be an $n-1$.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Thanks, fixed.

Comment: Your conclusion that they are unequal is wrong. The numerator in (1) ranges from $\frac n2$ to $\frac n4 - \frac 14$ and decreases in quarter steps, while the numerator in (2) ranges from $\frac 12$ to $n - \frac 12$ and increases integer steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proof by induction over $n$. Verify that the statement is true for $n=2$. Then the induction step is:

$$(-1)^{n+1}\binom{-\frac 12}{n+1} = - \frac{-\frac 12 -n}{n+1} (-1)^{n}\binom{-\frac 12}{n}= - \frac{-\frac 12 -n}{n+1} \frac 1{2^{2n}} \frac{2n\cdot\ldots \cdot \overbrace{(2n-n+1)}^{=n+1}}{n!} $$
$$= \frac 1{2^{2n+1}} \frac{(2n+1)2n\cdot\ldots\cdot \overbrace{(2n-n+2)}^{=2(n+1)-(n+1)+1}}{(n+1)!}\frac{2(n+1)}{2} =  \frac 1{2^{2(n+1)}} \binom{2(n+1)}{n+1}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$
\begin{align}
(-1)^n \binom{-\frac{1}{2}}{n} &=(-1)^n \frac{\overbrace{-\frac{1}{2}(-\frac{1}{2}-1)(-\frac{1}{2}-2)\ldots(-\frac{1}{2}-n+1)}^{n \text{factors}}}{n!} \\&= \frac{\overbrace{\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{2}+1)(\frac{1}{2}+2)\ldots(\frac{1}{2}+n-1)}^{n \text{factors}}}{n!} \\
&=\frac{1\times3\times5\dotsb (2n-1)}{n!2^n}\\
&=\frac{1\times3\times5\dotsb (2n-1)}{n!2^n}\times \frac{2\times 4\times 6\times \dotsb(2n)}{2\times 4\times 6\times \dotsb(2n)}\\
&=\frac{(2n)!}{n!2^n(n!2^n)}\tag{0}\\
&=2^{-2n}\binom{2n}{n}
\end{align}
$$
where in (0) we use the identity $2\times 4\times 6\times \dotsb(2n)=2^nn!$.